# How to get xmpp user after login into xmpp server successfully (iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

How to get XMPP user info after login into xmpp server successfully (iPhone SDK)?

After login successfully the following method called.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [XMPPFrameowrk](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/), then your `XMPPStream` instance has a `myJID` property that is overwritten in [handleBinding](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/Core/XMPPStream.m#1759) with the full JID that the server assigned you.

Comment: but i also need user status message, how can i get it ? Right now the problem i am facing is , i am not able to get status message (that the user set last time)  after login into app. However i am able to get presence updates once i am login into app, but status message lost after i quit and again login into app. i want to get XMPPUserCoreDataStorage and XMPPResourceCoreDataStorage objects with respect to login user.

Comment: The server only stores your presence while you're online.  If you want to persist it while you're offline, your app will need to store that info locally.

Comment: But if i store my status in locally and if i login into another device, in this case i will not get my status

Comment: Store it in jabber:iq:private (XEP-0049: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0049.html) or PEP (XEP-0163: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html) then.

Comment: i have tried using xep - 00489 and xep - 0163 in iphone sdk but didn't get any response from server.

Comment: looks like the server i am using "Openfire" is not supporting xep - 0049 and xep - 0163 extensions.